# Position Div on absolute right

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the current environment the following code works.

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 45px !important;
  left: 400px !important;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <input type="button" onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;" value="Previous Page" />
</div>
```

However it doesn't maintain its position and is not always on the right.

**How can this code be fixed so that:**

- div button always sticks to the right of the window
- div button maintains its position regardless of display resolution or window resizing i.e if different users have different monitor resolution the button should be in the same (right-side)place for all and should maintain its position with manual window resizing.

Comment: Maybe use `right` instead of `left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `right:0` instead of `left:400px`.  That puts the `div` on the right side of the page.  Since you have a `width:300px`, you'll need to `text-align:right` so that the button appears in the right side of the `div`.

```css
div.fixed {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 45px !important;
  right: 0px !important;
  width: 300px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <input type="button" onclick="location.href=document.referrer; return false;" value="Previous Page" />
</div>
```

As a side note, you generally want to avoid the use of `!important` where possible.  Sometimes, like when using some third party plugins, it may not be possible, but if you can override the style with better specificity that'd be preferable to `!important`.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much for such a quick resolution. To think I had to add a text-align. Wonders of being a javascript noob, lol. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you want your button to be positioned fixed in right side, regardless of screen resolution. The easy solution is use only right, instead of using css left parameter. I have created a working solution for you.

If you don't want the button be in fixed during scroll, but should scroll with content as well, then check float:right css property. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

```css
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input class="fixed" type="button" value="Previous Page" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      </br>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
            unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
                <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
            unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
                <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
            unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```